# aws dynamoDB cli - using jq on nested json

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I need to swap a value on a dynamoDB entry. The difficulty is the coworker who put the table together used nested json on the field I need to edit. I'm having trouble figuring out to how to edit a value when the layout is asymmetrical.

Let's say a row in dynamoDB shows up like this with get-item:

```
{    
 "Item": {
      "aws:rep:deleting": {
        "BOOL": false
      },
      "service": {
        "S": "g"
      },
      "settings": {
        "L": [
          {
            "M": {
              "fe_enabled": {
                "BOOL": false
              },
              "stack_type": {
                "S": "all"
              },
              "label": {
                "S": "helm_chart_name"
              },
              "value": {
                "S": "gate"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "M": {
              "fe_enabled": {
                "BOOL": true
              },
              "stack_type": {
                "S": "all"
              },
              "label": {
                "S": "helm_chart_version"
              },
              "value": {
                "S": "0.1.1"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "label": {
        "S": "gate"
      },
      "service_children": {
        "L": []
      },
      "independent": {
        "BOOL": true
      }
    }
}
```

I need to change `helm_chart_version`'s value to - say - `0.1.2`.

I've started by trying to isolate the value. I've tried variations of the following with no luck:

```
jq -r '.Item[].L.M | select(.label == "helm_4G_chart_version") | .value.S'
#  errors because there are multiple L's so it's iterating over null

jq '..|.label? | select(type != "null")'
#  discovered this neat syntax, but I can't figure out how to get value from that

jq --arg argName "argValue" '()' file.json | sponge file.json
#  this is likely the "replace" solution, but I don't know what to put in the () to get the right value
```

Also open to hearing that I'm tackling this incorrectly - I'm a little out of my depth here. I'm planning to save the edited json to a file and then doing a put-item on it. Is this the right way to edit a dynamoDB entry?

Comment: if you're interested, I could offer you an easy solution using another unix tool

Comment: @Dmitry sure, I'm all ears

Comment: using `jtc` (utility I developed), the solution would be like this: `jtc -w'<helm_chart_version>[-2][value][S]' -u'"0.1.2"' -f file.json` the flag `-f` provides in-place modification of the source file.

Comment: @Dmitry you're welcome to write it up into an answer! I'm leaning towards solutions that won't require me to install new tools, but it could be a valid solution for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to traverse individual objects and find the object to update and set its value, you can do

```
jq '(.Item.settings.L[] | select(.M.label.S == "helm_chart_version")) |= (.M.value.S = "0.1.2")'
```

the part before the `|=` does the identification of the right object matching your string. Once the object is identified, the update operator `|=` just modifies the field with the desired value. See it working on [jq-play](https://jqplay.org/s/EemeeJFIys)

Comment: two things: One: I think you'd need to change it to `Item.settings.L`, no? Secondly it's not erroring with that change, but it's also not changing the value. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex: I did not see an `.Item` field in the above JSON. Update the JSON and I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

If convenience is at a premium, then using `walk` has much to recommend it:

```
walk(if type == "object" and .label.S == "helm_chart_version"
     then .value.S = "0.1.2" else . end)
```

This of course assumes that "S" is known ahead of time. If that's not the case, then one possibility to consider would be:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("label") and any(.label[]; . == "helm_chart_version") 
     then .value |= map_values("0.1.2") else . end)
```

### Variations

If you don't want to `walk` the entire object, you could simply walk over `.settings`:

```
.Item.settings
|= walk(if type == "object" 
        and has("label")
        and any(.label[]; . == "helm_chart_version")
        then .value |= map_values("0.1.2")
        else . 
        end)
```

Or if "label" is also an unknown:

```
.Item.settings
|= (. as $in
    | [paths
       | . as $p
       | select(($in|getpath($p)) == "helm_chart_version")]
    | reduce .[] as $p ($in; setpath($p | (.[-2] = "value"); "0.1.2")))
```

Comment: I made a mistake in transcription and omitted Item: as a top level in the json. Wanted to let you know in case your solution needed updating

Comment: I don't appear to understand how to implement walk - I'm getting `jq: error: walk/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:` no matter what tweaks I make. Can you provide more context around how to use walk?

Comment: Since your jq is very old, now would be a good time to upgrade, but if that's not possible, simply google 'jq def walk builtin.jq` and include the def before invoking it.  One reason for using `walk` is to defend against unimportant changes to the overall structure of the incoming JSON.